# Spring boot: Getting 415 unsupported Media type

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, put, http-status-code-415

I am currently writing a spring boot backend with Rest-API and trying to write data against my database.
When doing a put ot post request, some strange things happen. Most of the time I get a `415 unsupported media type` error, but sometimes (for some of the entities) the put/ post request works fine and the data is written correctly against the datatbase.

But in most of the cases a 415-error occurs. If I understand the error stack trace correctly, the 415 error occurs because the body of my request cannot be read. I cannot figure out why!!

I tried out serveral things:

- Using `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`, `consumes = "application/json"` in the `@PutMapping`-Annotation,
- checking for loose `@JsonManagedReference` / `@JsonBackReference`,
- checking for standard constructor in entites,
- checking for getter/setter.
- adding `Content-Type: application/json` to the request in e.g.  Postman

But I cannot figure out, what the problem is.

Btw, I am using spring security and `@JsonView`-Annotation, not knowing if this is part of the problem.

Has anybody any idea???

Here is my Controller: `

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/source")
public class SourceController {

    private final SourceServiceImpl sourceServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    public SourceController(SourceServiceImpl sourceServiceImpl) {
        this.sourceServiceImpl = sourceServiceImpl;
    }

   
    @PostMapping(value = "/save")
    public void saveSource(@RequestBody SourceEntity sourceEntity){
        sourceServiceImpl.save(sourceEntity);
    }

    @PutMapping(value = "/update")
    public void updateSourcee(@RequestBody SourceEntity sourceEntity) {
        sourceServiceImpl.update(sourceEntity);
    }
}
```

Here is my Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "OWNER", name = "SOURCE")
public class SourceEntity {

    @JsonView(UntDataView.Basic.class)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sourceEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<FirmEntity> firmEntity;

    @JsonView(UntDataView.Basic.class)
    @Column(name = "desc")
    private String desc;

    @Column(name = "create_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer createId;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "create_id", nullable = false)
    private UserEntity userEntityCreate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "create_dat", nullable = false)
    private Date createDat;

    @Column(name = "corr_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer corrId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "corr_id")
    private UserEntity userEntityCorr;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "corr_dat")
    private Date corrDat;


    public SourceEntity() {
    }

    
//getter/ setter
```

Here is my request:
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMnBT.png) 
[PostmanHeader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVXUQ.png)

Here is the error:

```
"trace": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:225)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:158)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:131)
org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:170)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:67)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
",
 "message": "Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
 "path": "/source/update"
}
```

Comment: where is your request, what does it look like

Comment: @Toerktumlare sorry, I have added the request

Comment: What do you mean by ”in intellij”. That is not a complete request, and not reproducible. Use curl or screenshot postman etc.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I added a postman screenshot. Hope, this helps. I am really desperate ...

Comment: Can you show the HTTP headers of the request you sent from Postman?

Comment: can you please post your full debug logs, instead of just the exception.

Comment: have you tried removing things one by one to see if it works then. Start out with a clean entity without annotations.

Comment: At the end of the error trace says "path: /untadresse/save". Your call was supposed to execute /source/update. Do a debug setting a breakpoint in every public method of your controller, to make sure in which of them the error happens.

Comment: @LittleSanti Sorry, copy & paste error. I tried it with severals entities/ put requests.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Nothing shows in the run console when sending the put request. This is the only error I have. I tried to debug, but did not succeed. I think the error occured while Spring tries with `@ResponseBody` to convert  the return value to HTTP response body with HTTP Message converters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! I accidentally had two setters defined with different data types.